# twitter api returns "not recognised" on image tweets

Tags: php, json, image, api, twitter

I am trying to post a tweet with image using the api, I followed the instructions at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media-multiple-photos but it keeps returning
{"request":"/1.1/media/upload.json","error":"not recognized."}

My code is as follows:
I removed the tokens and secrets..

```
require('TwitterAPI.php');
$settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
        'consumer_key' => "",
        'consumer_secret' => ""
    );
$url = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json';
    $requestMethod = 'POST';
    $media_files = array(
      'myimage.jpg'
    );
$media_ids = array();
foreach ($media_files as $file) {
    $postfields = array(
            'media' => $file
        );
    }
$twitter = new TwitterAPI($settings);
    $response =  $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->setPostfields($postfields)
                 ->performRequest();
    $media_ids[] = $response->media_id_string;
    $media_ids = implode(',', $media_ids);
```